# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.example.owner.stock.Item

Tags: arraylist

I want to display a list in fragment. i am using a custom arraylist. it is giving me classcast exception. i searched for the soluo solvetion but it dosnt solve my problem. i am new to android so i have no idea how this.. can anyone help..

```
this is my Item class
public class Item  {
    public String item_name;
    public String item_desc;
    public String item_qty;


    public Item(String item_name, String item_desc,String item_qty) {
        super();
        this.item_name = item_name;
        this.item_desc = item_desc;
        this.item_qty = item_qty;
    }

    public String getItem_name(){
        return item_name;
    }

   public void setItem_name(String item_name)
    {
        this.item_name=item_name;
    }

   public String getItem_desc()
    {
        return  item_desc;
    }
   public  void setItem_desc(String item_desc)
    {
        this.item_desc=item_desc;
    }
    public String getItem_qty()
    {
        return  item_qty;
    }
    public void setItem_qty(String item_qty) {
        this.item_qty = item_qty;
    }
}
this is my addstock fragment

public class AddStock extends Fragment {

    EditText edit_item_name,edit_item_desc,edit_item_qty;
    Button btn_save;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_stock, container, false);

        edit_item_name = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.edittext_item_name);
       edit_item_desc = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText_item_desc);
       edit_item_qty = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText_item_qty);
       btn_save = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_Save);

        MainActivity act=(MainActivity)this.getActivity();
        final ArrayList stock = act.arrayList;

        btn_save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String item_name=edit_item_name.getText().toString();
                String item_desc=edit_item_desc.getText().toString();
                String item_qty=edit_item_qty.getText().toString();

                stock.add(item_name);
                stock.add(item_desc);
                stock.add(item_qty);

                Toast.makeText(AddStock.this.getActivity(), "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    return rootView;
    }
}
this is my viewstock fragment
public class ViewStock extends Fragment {

    public ViewStock() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootview= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_stock, container, false);

         ListView  listview = (ListView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.list);
       // Context mCtx = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        MainActivity act=(MainActivity)this.getActivity();
        ItemAdapter adapter = new ItemAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.list_item,act.arrayList);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        return  rootview;
    }
}

this is my main activity
Public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    NavigationView mNavigationView;
    FrameLayout mContentFrame;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private static final String PREFERENCES_FILE = "mymaterialapp_settings";
    private static final String PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "navigation_drawer_learned";
    private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";

    private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;
    private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
    private int mCurrentSelectedPosition;
    public ArrayList<Item> arrayList;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nav_drawer);

        setUpToolbar();
        arrayList=new ArrayList<Item>();
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.nav_drawer);

        mUserLearnedDrawer = Boolean.valueOf(readSharedSetting(this, PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, "false"));

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
            mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
        }

        setUpNavDrawer();

        mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        mContentFrame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.nav_contentframe);

        mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

                Fragment newFragment;
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                menuItem.setChecked(true);
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.navigation_item_1:
                        newFragment = new AddStock();
                        transaction.replace(R.id.nav_contentframe, newFragment);
                        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                        transaction.commit();
                        mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
                        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.navigation_item_2:
                        newFragment = new ViewStock();
                        transaction.replace(R.id.nav_contentframe, newFragment);
                        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                        transaction.commit();
                        mCurrentSelectedPosition = 1;
                        return true;
                    default:
                        return true;
                }
            }
        });
        //fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_contentframe, fragment).commit();

    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, 0);
        Menu menu = mNavigationView.getMenu();
        menu.getItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition).setChecked(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void setUpToolbar() {
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        if (mToolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        }
    }

    private void setUpNavDrawer() {
        if (mToolbar != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_drawer);
            mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                }
            });
        }

        if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
            saveSharedSetting(this, PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, "true");
        }

    }

    public static void saveSharedSetting(Context ctx, String settingName, String settingValue) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = ctx.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putString(settingName, settingValue);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public static String readSharedSetting(Context ctx, String settingName, String defaultValue) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = ctx.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPref.getString(settingName, defaultValue);
    }
}

this is my ItemAdapter 
public class ItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

        Context context;

    public ItemAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
                                 ArrayList<Item> items) {
        super(context, resourceId, items);
        this.context = context;
    }

   /*     public int getCount() {
            return items.size();
        }

        public Item getItem(int position) {
            return items.get(position);
        }

    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;
    }
*/
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            Item rowItem = getItem(position);
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (convertView == null) {

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

                holder.txtItemName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_item_name);
                holder.txtItemDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_item_desc);
                holder.txtItemQty = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_item_qty);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.txtItemName.setText(rowItem.getItem_name());
            holder.txtItemDesc.setText(rowItem.getItem_desc());
            holder.txtItemQty.setText(rowItem.getItem_qty());

            return convertView;
        }

        private class ViewHolder {
            TextView txtItemName;
            TextView txtItemDesc;
            TextView txtItemQty;
        }
}

this is the exception m getting

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to  com.example.owner.stock.Item
            at com.example.owner.stock.ItemAdapter.getView(ItemAdapter.java:60)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2344)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:698)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:759)
            at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1673)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2148)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15614)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4968)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15614)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4968)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15614)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4968)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1076)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15614)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4968)
            at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:907)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15614)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4968)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15614)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4968)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15614)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4968)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15614)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4968)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15614)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4968)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15614)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4968)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2102)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1859)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1077)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5884)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
07-22 23:34:00.334  20992-20992/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

Comment: Where is the custom array list you mention. This code is very hard to follow. Consider posting only code that you are having problems with

Comment: i am getting exception on row   Item rowItem = getItem(position); of ItemAdapter class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding String objects to a list that is typed to take Item objects.

Instead of:

```
stock.add(someString);
stock.add(someString);
stock.add(someString);
```

Do

```
stock.add(new Item(someString, someString, someString));
```

Comment: yes i got it but what is d solution for it . how can i take Item objects?

Comment: @user3623979 see above

Comment: great. Please mark the answer as resolved for other devs on the forums